# Solr Facet Limit And Start Point

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

My question is straight forward : we can do limit in solr facets. Is it possible to set the start point as well in facet results?

Like we do in normal query :->

```
query.setRows(5);

query.setStart(3);
```

I want my facet results to be started, say from 4th point, not from very first result.

In a related note, this can be done when using groups. I can select which group I want by passing start point in query. But this doesn't seem possible with facets. Can't use Groups because there is no sort by numfound feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faceting supports pagination using `facet.offset` and `facet.limit`.

[Using SolrJ](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_8_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/params/FacetParams.html), that should map to something like:

```
query.setParam(FacetParam.FACET_LIMIT, "1000"); // default is 100
query.setParam(FacetParam.FACET_OFFSET, "10"); // default is 0
```